# Separate cache per user or user group in Blitz cache

Tags: cache

We're using Blitz cache for a client website. Works fine.

Now we need to introduce variable content for different users (based on user groups)

Is it possible to have different cached versions per user or per user group?

For example, can we extend Blitz to alter the key (folder structure) under which a cached page is being saved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not possible to store different versions of cached pages. Your best bet would be to use the [dynamic content](https://putyourlightson.com/plugins/blitz#dynamic-content) feature that Blitz provides for injecting the content that can vary based on the user into the cached page.